# Why does wrapping printf with ld fail when there's a newline?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld

I'm trying to intercept calls to `printf` using `ld`'s `-wrap` option. I have the two files:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("printing\n");
    printf("printing");
}
```

printf_wrapper.c:

```
int __real_printf(const char *format, ...);

int __wrap_printf(const char *format, ...) {
    (void)format;
    return __real_printf("WRAPPED\n");
}
```

And I compile with the following command:

```
gcc -Wl,-wrap,printf *.c
```

When I run the resulting `a.out` binary, I get this output:

```
printing
WRAPPED
```

Why does the wrapping fail if there's a newline in the string? I checked my system's `stdio.h` and printf isn't a macro. This is with gcc 5.3.0

Comment: If you swap the order or have both with newline, what do you get?

Comment: Have you tried turning off optimization?  gcc might have changed your printf to something else, like puts.

Comment: If I swap the order in source, the order of the printing is swapped. Also, if I have both a newline and a variable (e.g. `printf("printing: %d\n", 1);'), then it is wrapped correctly

Comment: Compiling with -O0 gives the same result as omitting the optimization flag.

Comment: Look at using the -fno-builtin options

Comment: like -fno-builtin-printf

Comment: That did it. Compiling with -fno-builtin or -fno-builtin-printf gave the expected behavior (printing WRAPPED twice).

Comment: GCC will convert `printf("somestring\n")` to a call to `puts("somestring")` - even with optimization disabled (`-O0`) .  The `-fno-builtin-printf` option controls this behavior.

Comment: Suggest adding [gcc] tag

Comment: same thing applies to fprintf(), in that case use -fno-builtin-printf as @bruceg mentions in his answer.  In my tests this works well with -O3 -ffast-math, no conflicts, no reduction in performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the -fno-builtin option to tell gcc not to mess around with some specified functions.  So, if you added -fno-builtin-printf it should work.  In general it may cause some problems that would have been caught by the compiler to be missed.  See the gcc docs for details, e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html